# How can I find the country using latitude & longitude information using Pyspark & shapely

Tags: python, pyspark, geospatial, shapely

I have two table, one is presenting all countries and their respecting polygons & multipolygons.
Another one is presenting latitude and longitude Points() (`dist_base`).

My goal is here to "join" my point data to their respecting countries. I'm on `Pyspark` and I **can't** use `geopandas`, I'm then using `shapely` but the way I'm implementing it is really slow.

Do you have any advice using `shapely`?
(the idea would be to check in which polygoin my point is located).

What I tried is to check polygon after polygon (stored in `geodata_countries_geo`), if the point is inside, if yes, retrieve the ISO3 code associated (stored in a dictionnary `geodata_countries_geo_dict`)

```
import shapely.wkt as wkt

def check_nearest_country(lat, lon):
    point = Point(lon, lat)
    for geometry in geodata_countries_geo:
        polygon = wkt.loads(geometry[0])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            return str(geodata_countries_geo_dict.get(str(geometry[0])))
# register udf
check_nearest_country_udf = f.udf(lambda x,y: str(check_nearest_country(x,y)), StringType())
    
# apply
dist_base = dist_base.withColumn('Country_Base_ISO3', check_nearest_country_udf(f.col("lat"),f.col("lon")))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use geopandas in conjunction with [Pandas UDFs](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html), which speed up the whole process of spatial join a lot. This presumes that you can collect, through a `.toPandas()`, your countries dataframe as I think it is not very large - there are not so many countries in the world.

The process is as follows - comments are before each code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType



# create sample pyspark.DataFrame of points
df_points = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1.23, 4.56],
  [-1.23, -4.56],
  [0.0, 0.0]
], ['lon', 'lat'])
df_points.show()
# +-----+-----+
# |  lon|  lat|
# +-----+-----+
# | 1.23| 4.56|
# |-1.23|-4.56|
# |  0.0|  0.0|
# +-----+-----+



# create sample geopandas.GeoDataFrame of countries
df_countries = pd.DataFrame({
  'country': ['ITA', 'UK', 'JPN'],
  'polygon': ['POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1),(2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 3,2 2))', 
              'POLYGON((10 10,50 10,50 50,10 50,10 10),(20 20, 30 20, 30 30, 20 30,20 20))',
              'POLYGON((-1 -1,-5 -1,-5 -5,-1 -5,-1 -1),(-2 -2, -3 -2, -3 -3, -2 -3,-2 -2))']
})
geometry = df_countries['polygon'].apply(wkt.loads)
df_countries = df_countries.drop(columns=['polygon'])
gdf_countries = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_countries, crs="epsg:4326", geometry=geometry)
print(gdf_countries)
#   country                                           geometry
# 0     ITA  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 5.00000 1.00000, 5....
# 1      UK  POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 50.00000 10.00000...
# 2     JPN  POLYGON ((-1.00000 -1.00000, -5.00000 -1.00000...



# define Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf('string', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def spatial_join_udf(lat: pd.Series, lon: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    point_var = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(lon, lat)]
    gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}), crs='epsg:4326', geometry=point_var)
    gdf_joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf_points, gdf_countries, how='left')
    return gdf_joined['country']



# perform spatial join between points and countries
df_points \
  .withColumn('country', spatial_join_udf(df_points['lat'], df_points['lon'])) \
  .show()
# +-----+-----+-------+
# |  lon|  lat|country|
# +-----+-----+-------+
# | 1.23| 4.56|    ITA|
# |-1.23|-4.56|    JPN|
# |  0.0|  0.0|   null|
# +-----+-----+-------+
```

If you want more information, here's the docs for the function [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html).

Comment: Many thanks for your really understandable answer ! Problems, I can't use ```geopandas``` in my working environment!

Comment: But you are right, I can go throw ```toPandas()```. I'm trying to implement ```rtree``` indexing

Comment: Sorry, I erroneously thought that you couldn't use it for memory issues, not because you don't have it in your worker environment.  Let me know if I can help